# Finding what zoom level would be used with a lat/long span

Tags: android, android-mapview

I know the span of the latitude and longitude that I want to have included in my view. I do not want to use `zoomToSpan()`, I want to use `animateTo()`. Is there a way to determine what the zoom level of the map will be, before actually getting to that location? Basically convert the bounds of the span into a zoom level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to reverse-engineer it:

1.) Create a test app with a mapview and record the span values for each zoom level (using Logcat).

2.) In your real app, create a HashMap from span values to zoom level and populate it with the data you've collected in Step 1.

3.) So now, all you have to do is figure out what zoom value does your required span value correspond to and this can be done efficiently by doing a look up using the HashMap created in Step 2.

Comment: Actually not a bad way of doing it. I was hoping there was a more elegant solution, but for the time being I can definitely try to make this work. I'll give it a shot and mark this as answered pending my results. Thanks Vishwa!

Comment: Yea, I agree, not the most elegant solution but also not the most hackish I guess. Do let me know how it works!